# Relação dos veículos que estão sem fotos

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, select

Eu preciso da relação dos veículos que ainda não possuem fotos cadastradas.
Tenho uma tabela de Veículos, uma tabela ImagenVeiculo e uma outra TipoImagem.

Exemplo:

```
tbVeiculo (VeiculoId, DataCadastro, Etc...)  
tbImagemVeiculo (ImagemVeiculoId, VeiculoId, TipoImagemId, Imagem, Data, Etc...)  
tbTipoImagem ( TipoImagemId, Nome, Etc...)
```

Eu preciso saber também quais os tipos de imagens ele ainda não inseriu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você só precisa a cláusula `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbVeiculo v
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tbImagemVeiculo iv
                   WHERE iv.VeiculoId = v.VeiculoId)
```

E para verificar por tipo de imagem, faça um `CROSS JOIN` com a tabela `tbTipoImagem`:

```
SELECT v.*,
       ti.*
  FROM tbVeiculo v
 CROSS JOIN tbTipoImagem ti
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tbImagemVeiculo iv
                   WHERE iv.VeiculoId = v.VeiculoId
                     AND iv.TipoImagemId = ti.TipoImagemId)
```

---

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a `subquery` returns any rows at all, `EXISTS subquery` is `TRUE`, and `NOT EXISTS` subquery is `FALSE`

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a `subquery` retornar qualquer linha, `EXISTS` será `VERDADEIRO`, e `NOT EXISTS` será `FALSO`

Comment: +1 Me ajudou muito, eu esqueci de mencionar na pegunta, mas eu precisa saber também quais os tipos de imagens ele ainda não inseriu. Nessa seleção eu só consigo sabe se ele inseriu alguma imagem correto?

Comment: @Jhonas inclui na ultima edição da resposta a resolução para seu questionamento

Answer (score 0):

Oi,

Sem saber as chaves primária e externa fica dificil mas você pode usar um NOT IN algo parecido com isso

```
SELECT veiculos.* from tbVeiculo veiculos
where veiculos.id NOT IN (SELECT imagem.id_veiculo from tbImagemVeiculo imagem join tbTipoImagem  tipo on imagem.id = tipo.id_tipo )
```

Comment: `tbTipoImagem` você usa pra que?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que isso resolva seu problema

```
SELECT
  v.*
FROM tbVeiculo v
WHERE v.id NOT IN (SELECT
  i.id_veiculo
FROM tbImagemVeiculo i
INNER JOIN tbTipoImagem t
  ON i.id = t.id_tipo)
```

Comment: `tbTipoImagem` você usa pra que?